# Get links of particular owner in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to display links, with say owner id 5. how can i achieve this in wordpress. thanks in advance for any suggestions or help. 
I found this [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_bookmarks) . but there is no option to mention link_owner id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are pulling the posts of the currently logged in user, then you can use [get_the_author_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_posts) or [the_author_posts_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_posts_link).

If not, then you can use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). Check out the Author params and let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: I am using feedwordpress plugin.and I am finding difficult to replace original plugin code to display the links for only logged in user. I managed to solve the problem by putting if condition to check author id, under for each link. thanks a lot for your reply Edenbauer. I'll vote up your reply.

Comment: I am having another issue now, that admin layout is breaking in internet explorer 7 & 8 , when I am using Feedwordpress plugin. http://feedwordpress.radgeek.com/